# Get Maximum value from JSON object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have JSON like

```
var JObject = [
     {
        a:"A1",
        b:100,
        c:800
     },
     {
       a:"B1",
       b:300, 
       c:400
      } 
  ];
```

I need maximum value from this JSON...it has to return 800 if it return key and column index

Comment: It isn't JSON!. You just have an object

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is not a `JSON` object - why not just iterate and keep a variable `max` along the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
var JObject = [{
  a: "A1",
  b: 100,
  c: 800
}, {
  a: "B1",
  b: 300,
  c: 400
}];

var res = Math.max.apply(null,JObject.map(function(v) { 
// iterate over array element and getting max value from result array 
  
  var r = [];
  for (var val in v) {
  // iterate over object inside array
    if (v.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
      var num = parseInt(v[val], 10);
      // parsing the value for integer output
      r.push(isNaN(num) ? 0 : num);
      // pushing  value to array, in case of `Nan` pushing it as 0
    }
  }
  return Math.max.apply(null,r);
  // getting max value from object values
}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged in d3.
I will give a d3 answer.

Working code below

```js
var kary = [
     {
        a:"A1",
        b:100,
        c:800
     },
     {
       a:"B1",
       b:1300, 
       c:400
      },
       {
       a:"D1",
       b:300, 
       c:400
      } 

  ];

var max = d3.max(kary, function(d){ return d3.max(d3.values(d).filter(function(d1){ return !isNaN(d1)}))});

console.log(max)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could make this more or less generic - and probably shorten it into a single reduce statement.

```
var data = [
  {a:"A1",b:100,c:800},
  {a:"B1",b:300,c:400}
];

data
  .reduce(function(acc, x, i) {
    if (x.b > x.c) {
        return acc.concat({key: 'b', value: x.b });
    }
    return acc.concat({key: 'c', value: x.c });
  }, [])
  .reduce(function(acc, x, i) {
    if (x.value > acc.value) {
      return {
        key: x.key,
        value: x.value,
        index: i
      };
    }
    return acc;
  }, {key: '', value: Number.MIN_VALUE, index: -1});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library like lodash or underscore you can simply do:

```
_.max(_.map(JObject, function(a){
  return _.max(_.values(a));
}));
```

You can also solve it with reduce:

`_.reduce(JObject, function(val, a){
   return _.max(_.values(a)) > val ? _.max(_.values(a)) : val;
},0);`